# SSH login using Ubuntu's terminal - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm using ubuntu system to login to remote server using ssh. SSH is configured in my system and I can see my public ssh key but when I try something like `ssh xx.xx.xx.xx` it throws error Permission denied (publickey).

For the IP address which I'm trying to access, ssh username is `ec5-user` without any password.

Do I have to switch to that user in my ubuntu terminal before using `ssh xx.xx.xx.xx` ? Using putty, I'm able to login from windows system.

If I do `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, it gives soething like

```
2048 aa:b5:51:76:de:42:12:78:a1:ff:9e:74:d8:7d:59:24  amit@amit-Inspiron-N5010 (RSA)
```

Comment: Do you have the right Public key?

Comment: And can you login via password auth?

Comment: @Daniel: I've updated the question with more details. Please check Related issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/656713/uninstalling-ssh

Comment: Based on comments from the answer by @carlo, you can't find the second machine, please try putting `PasswordAuthentication yes` in the second machines SSH configuration http://askubuntu.com/questions/337757/how-to-fix-permission-denied-public-key-error Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/137165/git-ssh-permission-denied-publickey For a working solution

Comment: See my answer, please

Comment: @amitshree Please have a look into same errmsg as Yours, where they found the problem in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. (This should have been a comment, but I have a sooo bad reputation...). By prometheos.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to fix the issue at the time. Instead I've used filezilla to make my changes. Please read solutions/comments given by people here which might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check .ssh folder permission (run `ls -laR ~/.ssh`):

.ssh folder should have 700, while private key 600 and the public one can have 644.

Moreover, you can have more information about the problem running ssh with full debug logs

```
ssh -vvv ...
```

Comment: Here is the output of ls -laR ~/.ssh   `/home/amit/.ssh:
total 52
drwx------  3 amit amit  4096 Jul 29 20:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 49 amit amit 20480 Jul 30 12:24 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 amit amit     0 Jun  2 15:26 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 amit amit  1766 Jan 26  2015 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 amit amit   402 Jun  2 15:31 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 amit amit 12288 Jul 29 20:17 .id_rsa.pub.swp
-rw-r--r--  1 amit amit  3538 Jul  8 11:26 known_hosts
drwxrwxr-x  3 amit amit  4096 Jun  2 14:41 retailon_referral`

Comment: According to the output of ls -laR ~/.ssh   `/home/amit/.ssh:
is having permission 700. Should I uninstall completely SSH and install it again?

Comment: It is quite hard to read you comment, next time please format the code.
Anyway, permissions look fine. What about the output of `ssh -vvv ...` (full debug infos)?

Comment: `OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014'  
  `debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config`  
`debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *`  
`ssh: Could not resolve hostname ...: Name or service not known`

Comment: `Name or service not known` means that it could not find the machine you are trying to connect to, it is not a problem of permissions.
Moreover, I will try to follow Daniel's suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to ssh to ec5-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.  OK, they way ssh works is as follows:

ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx = ssh [my username]@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

ssh bob@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx = ssh bob@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

So, you need to either log in to the same username, or you need to specify what username you're trying to ssh to.

Answer (score 0):

If the comments above are correct that you are indeed getting `Could not resolve hostname`, this means that Ubuntu has no idea how to find the hostname you're giving it. Can you log in via the IP address?

**If** using the IP address works fine and you're having issues connecting to a hostname (which the error seems to indicate), you can modify your `/etc/hosts` file to include the node you are trying to connect to. Just enter the hostname and IP address you want it tied to like so:

*EXAMPLE*

```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   192.168.1.10    foo.mydomain.org       foo
   192.168.1.13    bar.mydomain.org       bar
   146.82.138.7    master.debian.org      master
   209.237.226.90  www.opensource.org
```

> Fields of the entry are separated by any number of  blanks  and/or  tab
>          characters.   Text  from a "#" character until the end of the line is a
>          comment, and is ignored.  Host  names  may  contain  only  alphanumeric
>          characters, minus signs ("-"), and periods (".").  They must begin with
>          an  alphabetic  character  and  end  with  an  alphanumeric  character.
>          Optional aliases provide for name changes, alternate spellings, shorter
>          hostnames, or generic hostnames (for example, localhost).

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/hosts.5.html