# Uninstalling ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh

ssh is installed in my system.

```
      ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

But when I try to uninstall it completely using `sudo apt-get purge openssh-server` it says `Package 'openssh-server' is not installed, so not removed`.
How I can remove it completely? I was having issue [SSH login using Ubuntu's terminal - Permission denied (publickey)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654252/ssh-login-using-ubuntus-terminal/654256), so I wanted to un-install it and again re-install it.

As suggested by Mark in the answer/comments, I've uninstalled ssh using synaptic package manager, still ssh -V was showing it's there. What might be the issue?

[image]

As suggested, again I've reinstalled it, still I'm getting [SSH login using Ubuntu's terminal - Permission denied (publickey)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654252/ssh-login-using-ubuntus-terminal/654256) issue.

While searching for `ssh` in synaptic package manager, when ssh is installed, instead of showing ssh meta package, it shows something like the attached image.
[image]

Comment: ssh server isn't installed by default, ssh server has to be manually installed. What you have is the client, the thing that allows going from the box to another box. Mark's answer suits you the most

Comment: @markkirby: Sorry about the confusion. I've updated the question.

Comment: @amitshree  That one called ssh is the meta package, the description should say `secure shell client and server (metapackage)`, It says it is installed any way, I am going too post on your other question as that is the real issue here. Thanks for updateing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my system the package `openssh-server` is not installed, it is called `openssh-client`

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-client
```

If it is still there

```
dpkg --listfiles openssh-client
```

Will give you the locations and name of all `openssh-client` packages

After looking around, openssh has many preinstalled packages, removing the client alone did not remove ssh from the system, however here is a way to get rid of it all

First you need synaptic package manager

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Open this, enter password and in the search box put `ssh`, now, you see the package just called `ssh` ? That is an ssh meta package, uninstalling this should remove ssh from the system completely.

[image]

Comment: Faster than me =) +1

Comment: @mark: `sudo apt-get purge openssh-client` says `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`

Comment: You are using another package manager at the same time, please make sure `apt` is only running once

Comment: Make sure that synaptic, system update, and others are not running.

Comment: @markkirby: Ok, Now I was able to purge using `openssh-client`. Still `ssh -V` says it's there.  `dpkg --listfiles openssh-client` gives `/.
/etc
/etc/ssh
/etc/ssh/moduli
/etc/ssh/ssh_config
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/openssh
/usr/lib/openssh/ssh-keysign
/usr/lib/openssh/ssh-pkcs11-helper
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/openssh-client` etc.

Comment: Please see my update for a full removel

Comment: Do you need to remove the client? It's harmless. No one can ssh into your box without an (active) ssh server.

Comment: @SimonHoare Don't ask me ask the OP in there question, I just do what they ask for, they probably just want to clear any junk from there system

Comment: @SimonHoare: I wanted to remove it and again install it. Isn't that recommended? I was having issue [SSH login using Ubuntu's terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/654252/ssh-login-using-ubuntus-terminal/654256)  which I wasn't able to solve, so I though I should remove it and again install it?

Comment: No that sounds fine. Hope it helps.

Comment: @amitshree You just want to reinstall it ? Why did you not say that before, removal and reinstall are NOT the same, I will update this to answer to reflect this, but need to know, `ssh server` is not fully installed by default, would you like it fully installed ?

Comment: @amitshree Please open synaptic and install that `meta` package for `ssh`, this will install it all again, based on your other question, you don't need to reinstall `ssh` you need too add the ip/hostname in the local computer /etc/hosts file. Simple http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ssh-name-or-service-not-known-479307/

Answer (score 3):

The command `ssh` is part of the package `openssh-client`

Therefore remove it with

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-client
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the ssh service before un-installing it.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh stop
```

or

```
sudo service ssh stop
```

Then do

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove openssh-client openssh-server
```

Comment: Sorry @Mitch, but I don't understand. The error message in OPs question is `Package 'openssh-server' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: `sudo service ssh stop` says `ssh: unrecognized service`. Why so??

Comment: What about the first command?

Comment: first command says `sudo: /etc/init.d/ssh: command not found`

Comment: You may have removed it, or its not running.

Answer (score 1):

You have the client. To be sure, type the following:

```
dpkg -l | grep openssh-client
```

Note that the client is harmless. It is for you to tunnel into other machines. It doesn't include an SSH server that would give an attacker (or anyone) SSH access to your computer.

Comment: it gives something like `ii  libssh-4:amd64                                        0.6.1-0ubuntu3.1                                    amd64        tiny C SSH library`

Comment: Ok - not the client but a library. In any case, you don't have the server installed. As for what the library is for, I don't know.